# Duckling send JSON to parse method ('Need a 'text' parameter to parse' error)

Tags: bash, named-entity-extraction, duckling

I work with Duckling, whish works on my local machine on port 8000. via CURL. Requests of the following type:

```
curl -X POST https://0.0.0.0:8000/parse -d 'locale=en_GB&text=tomorrow at eight'
```

executed successfully.

But when I do so:

```
curl -X POST https://0.0.0.0:8000/parse -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"locale": "en_GB", "text": "tomorrow at eight"}'
```

The HTTP 422 code is returned with the message "Need a 'text' parameter to parse".

How to correctly pass JSON to Duckling?

Comment: Try to change the `json=` parameter to `data=` parameter in the second `request.post`

Comment: No, it's a way that doesn't fit. I need to pass the JSON object, not the separated parameters as data

Comment: The question is reformulated - interested in transferring JSON object to Duckling using a POST request